# USB device - 0cf3:9271 - Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n drops wifi after some time of usage

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, wpa-supplicant, ath9k

**TL;DR**: After a week-long investigation, I think either the ath9k_htc firmware is broken, or a large proportion of the 0cf3:9271 devices is buggy. My next plan is to purchase or pick up a different wifi adapter that avoids the firmware. My inspection of the ath9k_htc driver suggests that all Atheros 9271 chips use this firmware.

After I updated my system from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, my USB wifi adapter has dropping my connection after some time of usage. I can fix the problem temporarily by unplugging the adapter and plugging it back in, but I would like to fix the underlying problem so that the device stops doing this completely. I do not know where to start looking, however.

`lsb_release -a`:

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I enabled debug logs for the ath9k_htc driver. Apart from that config change, I built the kernel from the same sources as the Linux kernel debian package from Ubuntu's repos, which I acquired with `apt-get source linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-70-generic`

`uname -a`:

```
Linux herpcomp 5.4.94afw #1 SMP Sat Apr 10 21:27:47 PDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is a link to an excerpt from running `journalctl` - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kmV4MYKDYB/. I think I caught the moment where the device acting weirdly since I see there is a log line saying:

> Apr 11 16:59:14 herpcomp kernel: wlx00c0ca82d3fc: deauthenticated from 04:d9:f5:b1:f8:30 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)

Here is also a set of logs specifically showing NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant around the time where my adapter started acting weirdly: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gW7s5rsMhC/. This was retrieved with `journalctl -S "2021-04-11 16:55:00" -U "2021-04-11 17:10:00" -u NetworkManager -u wpa_supplicant`.

This is the contents of /etc/NetworkManager.d/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf:

```
$ cat default-wifi-powersave-on.conf 
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

`sudo iw reg get` shows:

```
global
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2400 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5730 - 5850 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

phy#0
country GB: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

Since I live in the US, I assume the `global` option is set correctly. I'm not sure why `phy#0` is set to GB, though, and I don't know how to change it.

Any ideas about where else I should look to find the problem? My next guess is to search for logs and configurations related to wpa_supplicant, and do a bit of research on what `iw reg get/set` is actually doing. I'll leave updates as I work on this problem.

**EDIT 1:** I added in a link to some logs I got from running `journalctl -S "2021-04-11 16:55:00" -U "2021-04-11 17:10:00" -u NetworkManager -u wpa_supplicant`. The time interval contains the moments where my wireless adapter acted weirdly. The logs are pasted at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gW7s5rsMhC/.

Interestingly, I found the following sequence of logs from reading the kernel, NetworkManager, and wpa_supplicant logs together:

```
Apr 11 16:59:05 herpcomp kernel: ath: phy1: AWAKE -> FULL-SLEEP
Apr 11 16:59:05 herpcomp kernel: ath: phy1: Set HW Key
Apr 11 16:59:05 herpcomp kernel: ath: phy1: FULL-SLEEP -> AWAKE
Apr 11 16:59:05 herpcomp kernel: ath: phy1: AWAKE -> FULL-SLEEP
Apr 11 16:59:05 herpcomp wpa_supplicant[1212]: wlx00c0ca82d3fc: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=04:d9:f5:b1:f8:30 reason=0
Apr 11 16:59:05 herpcomp NetworkManager[1174]: <info>  [1618185545.3145] device (wlx00c0ca82d3fc): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 11 16:59:05 herpcomp kernel: ath: phy1: FULL-SLEEP -> AWAKE
Apr 11 16:59:05 herpcomp kernel: ath: phy1: Set channel: 2452 MHz
```

I am not too entirely sure what it means when the ath9k_htc driver says that the device is going from "AWAKE" to "FULL-SLEEP", but that looks very suspicious.

**EDIT 2**: I collected some 2 sets of logs from wpa_supplicant. This first file are logs when I was unable to connect to my router: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5VBk27GXTZ/

This second file of logs are when I successfully connected to my router: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4YT8FtR3zg/

In the first file that describes my wifi card's inability to connect with the router, I found that message 1 of the 4 way handshake was being repeated constantly. The router (which I will call the access point, or AP, here) would send me message 1 containing the AP's ANonce. wpa_supplicant would then respond back with the SNonce that was just generated. Then, the AP would respond back with the same message 1 again, rather than message 3 of the 4 way handshake.

This did not occur at all under the successful case. In that case, the 4 way handshake proceeds smoothly. AP sent me message 1. wpa_supplicant responded with message 2. AP sent back message 3, and wpa_supplicant completes the handshake by sending back message 4.

I further confirmed this weird behavior with wireshark. I found that when I was unable to connect to the AP, the AP was just constantly sending the same message 1. Then, I compared the 4 way handshakes when I could not connect with the case where I could connect. I found no differences in the AP's message 1 across the two cases.

I also compared wpa_supplicant's response in a case of failure and a case of success; apart from the differences in SNonce and the message integrity check, the response from wpa_supplicant are the same.

At this point, I'm thinking that the AP is not behaving correctly. I haven't solved the problem completely yet, but I have at least narrowed down the likely problem areas.

**EDIT 3**: I made a discovery tonight! I used `diff` on the two sets of logs I retrieved from wpa_supplicant. One set of logs followed my system when the connection was successful, and the other set of logs were when my connections were failures. I found that the ANonces I was receiving from the router were different in two locations:

First logs show:

> 4a 47 9e 38 c5 1b fc e4 c1 b2 73 7d 9a 2d 8f 34 3c 68 80 b2 bb c0 b0 ed ce ec 5f 55 1a 4e 36 d**6**

Second logs show:

> 4a 47 9e 38 c5 1b fc e4 c1 b2 73 7d 9a 2d 8f 34 3c 68 80 b2 bb c0 b0 ed ce ec 5f 55 1a 4e 36 d**a**

The two nonces are almost exactly the same. The only difference is in the last 4 bits (the last hex digit in the above pair of strings).

This would explain my router's behavior. wpa_supplicant is calculating MICs using a different nonce than what the router is using.

Now the problem becomes wondering why the last 4th and 3rd to last bits are different.

I had already tried connecting my system to my phone's hotspot when wifi connections were failing, and I found that my system showed the same symptoms as when it failed to connect to the router. Since I encountered the same problem when I used my phone rather than the router, I doubt the router is sending me the wrong nonce. I assume that something on my system is collecting data from the router incorrectly.

My search will probably start somewhere in the ath9k_htc driver again. I doubt wpa_supplicant's nl80211 driver is misbehaving; otherwise I would expect to see this problem in many users' systems, which would have probably collected the attention of wpa_supplicant's maintainers.

**EDIT 4**: I took a closer look at the nonces. I found that each time wpa_supplicant failed the 4way handshake, the next attempt would include a nonce that was 1 integer larger than the previous nonce. For example, if I look at the last 2 bytes of the nonce, I see the following from each handshake attempt:

```
db 07
db 08
db 09
db 0a
db 0b
db 0c
db 0d
db 0e
```

Something is incrementing the nonces. I'm wondering if the replay counter could be related, since that counter is incremented on each handshake attempt. Perhaps the replay counter's memory location is overlapping with the key?

**EDIT 5:** After a lengthy week-long investigation, I've found that the driver isn't misbehaving. The networking stack in the kernel isn't misbehaving. wpa_supplicant is not misbehaving. It seems that there is just something wrong very low-level. I also recall I had a similar (probably the same) problem with another wifi adapter that had the same USB vendor and device ID as my currently wonky adapter. I conclude that there is either something wrong with the firmware, or something wrong with the a large proportion of these 0cf3:9271 chips.

I think I will just have to pick up a different wifi card or a different wifi adapter altogether.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Thanks! I added some logs for NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant around the time where the device behaved weirdly. I posted my thoughts under EDIT 1. I will post my thoughts here in the comment section for convenience as well. I see that the kernel driver is bringing the device to "FULL-SLEEP" from "AWAKE" around the same time where the "CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED" is logged from wpa_supplicant. That seems suspicious to me, but I do not fully understand what the sleeping or awake device means yet. I thought I configured NetworkManager to never use wifi.powersave. I will do some more research.

Comment: I have added in two additional links to two more sets of logs. These logs show that the access point is repeating message 1 of the 4 way handshake, even after wpa_supplicant has responded with message 2 of 4.

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the router, but I assume that if I use a different MAC address, the router would be forced to ignore the cached pairwise master key that was associated with my card's previous MAC address, so the router would be treating the connection as brand new. I'm hoping this would help me step through the 4 way handshake cleanly.

Comment: I made a minor discovery tonight. I learned that my wifi adapter is unable to connect to my phone's hotspot. Wireshark shows a problem that has the same symptoms: message 1 of the 4 way handshake is being sent repeatedly to my wifi card. I think the probability that I have 2 misbehaving access points is quite low, so I think wpa_supplicant is miscalculating the MIC. I will investigate more later after following https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/244316/how-is-the-mic-message-integrity-code-generated-in-wpa2.

Comment: Another night of debugging! I inspected the logs from wpa_supplicant and the source of wpa_supplicant. Everything in wpa_supplicant seems to be running fine. I found nothing that would suggest that wpa_supplicant was miscalculating the MIC or the PTK, nor was wpa_supplicant sending a different SNonce. I thought these situations might occur if wpa_supplicant had a special branch for weird edge cases, but I didn't see anything like that. My best conclusion right now is that the router is probably misbehaving. I did reboot the router last night, so I will see how it runs tonight.

Comment: I made a discovery tonight. It looks like the nonces that wpa_supplicant is using is different from what the router is using. The chances of two different nonces being generated randomly and being that close to each other is far too small; it's more likely that something in my system is changing a small number of bits in the received nonce.

Comment: I did a bit more debugging. wpa_supplicant is picking up the ANonce from the socket opened at https://salsa.debian.org/debian/wpa/-/blob/f8fcfdd2daed5fdf901eac74a038e1d5f6ab3e55/src/l2_packet/l2_packet_linux.c#L289. It doesn't look like the buffer containing the nonce is being changed after it is filled with data from the socket, so the problem could be coming from the kernel. However, I also had this problem when I tried testing with the older 18.04 kernel that previously had no issues on 18.04, which could imply the problem is even lower level. For now, I tried uncoiling my USB wire.

Comment: I checked what the ath9k_htc kernel driver was receiving from the USB device. I was able to compare the key nonces from the USB device to what I was seeing in wpa_supplicant. The key nonces received by the kernel and wpa_supplicant were the same as each other, meaning that there probably wasn't a networking or driver bug affecting me here. There could be a problem in the USB system, but that seems unlikely for such an important part of the kernel. I think something might be up with the firmware loaded on my device. I will try the firmware installed by the `firmware-ath9k-htc` package.

Comment: Okay. The error just occurred again with the new firmware. I'll stop my investigation here, and I'll just conclude that there is either something wrong with the firmware, there is something broken with my card, or there is something wrong with the entire line of chips.